# Assign a C++ out reference to something that was destroyed?

Tags: c++, stl, pass-by-reference

So I'm looking through some code, and I see this:

```
class whatever 
{
public:
    void SomeFunc(SomeClass& outVal)
    {
        outVal = m_q.front();
        m_q.pop();
    }

private:
    std::queue<SomeClass> m_q;
};
```

This doesn't seem like outVal would be a valid reference any more...  However, it appears to work.

I've seen this in other code before too, is this valid?  Thanks

Comment: I think it's useful to think about what would happen if that *would* reseat the reference. I.e what happens if you do: `int &r = *new int; delete &r;`, after which `r` references nothing anymore. I think that this is all right, as long as you don't evaluate `r` anymore after the delete. So this is UB: `int &r = *new int; delete &r; r;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that references are not like pointers: they cannot be **rebound** after their creation. That means that if I do

```
int a;
int b;
int &c = a;
```

Then throughout that scope, an assignment to c will actually mean an assignment to a. So,

```
int a = 2;
{
   int b = 3;
   int &c = a;
   c = b;
   b = -5;
}
printf("%d",a); // prints "3".
```

So, in this case, the reference is not being **pointed at** a deleted object. Rather, the return value of `m_q.front()` is **copied into** whatever outVal references, via the assignment operator.

Comment: Exactly, there is a copy there. Even if it looks like outval would be out of scope, remember it's not local to the function, is just an alias to an outside variable.

Comment: Yeah even after a few years of C++ references still confuse me sometimes :).  Pointers just seem so much more intuitive!

Comment: Yeah, I never really saw any value to using C++ references instead of pointers.

Comment: @Crashworks: it's more a matter of 'contract', you don't check that a reference points to null, you just assumes it points to a valid object!

Answer (score 2):

What I wrote in my previous reply was complete nonsense. (Whoever upvoted my original response, please take it back :)

In this example the reference is not bound to a dying object, but rather the value of the object in the front is copied to another object (referred to by the reference). The copy continues to exist independently of the queue an the fact that the front of the queue is destroyed has no adverse effects on the copy.

Please, refer to Crashworks reply for a great explanation of what is happening here.

Comment: didn't upvote you, but -1 because you asked for it and +1 for admitting and correcting your own fault. let's say we are even :)

Answer (score 2):

It's valid. You are not reseating the `outVal` reference to refer to `m_q.front()`, that is not something supported by references, instead you are assigning `m_q.front()` to the variable (actually lvalue) that `outVal` refers to.

```
  SomeClass c;
  someWhatever.SomeFunc(c);
```

Can be thought of as behaving like:

```
  SomeClass c;
  c = someWhatever.m_q.front();
  someWhater.m_q.pop();
```